# Creating a calculator in JS and getting an undefined. Beginner Programer

Tags: javascript, calculator

So I'm creating a calculator that does a pretty simple calculation. Just some simple math. However there is one property that has a lot of different variables. The original program was written in jQuery so I had to redo the properties to work with our sites regular Javascript framework. I think it's a problem with one of the declared variables. If you run the program, you get the answer "undefined" like it's missing a variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var volts = document.getElementById("voltDrop_volts")[0].value;
var acdc = document.getElementById("voltDrop_acdc")[0].value;
var amps = document.getElementById("voltDrop_amps")[0].value;
var length = document.getElementById("voltDrop_ft")[0].value;
var awg = document.getElementById("voltDrop_awg")[0].value;
var ohm = 0;

if (awg === 36) { ohm = 371.0; }
else if (awg === 34) { ohm = 237.0; }
else if (awg === 32) { ohm = 164.0; }
else if (awg === 30) { ohm = 103.0; }
else if (awg === 28) { ohm = 64.9; }
else if (awg === 26) { ohm = 37.3; }
else if (awg === 24) { ohm = 23.3; }
else if (awg === 22) { ohm = 14.7; }
else if (awg === 20) { ohm = 10.0; }
else if (awg === 18) { ohm = 6.4; }
else if (awg === 16) { ohm = 4.0; }
else if (awg === 14) { ohm = 2.5; }
else if (awg === 12) { ohm = 1.6; }
else if (awg === 10) { ohm = 1.1; }
else if (awg === 8) { ohm = .62; }
else if (awg === 6) { ohm = .40; }
else if (awg === 4) { ohm = .24; }
else if (awg === 2) { ohm = .16; }
else if (awg === 1) { ohm = .13; }
else if (awg === '1/0') { ohm = .096; }
else if (awg === '2/0') { ohm = .077; }
else if (awg === '3/0') { ohm = .062; }
else if (awg === '4/0') { ohm = .049; }
else { msg = "Error"; }

var vDrop = ((ohm * 2) * (length / 1000) * amps);
var vFinal = (volts - vDrop);

function formReset()
    {
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
    }
function printAnswer()
    {
        document.getElementById("theAnswer").innerHTML = vFinal;
    }
</script>
```

I'm gonna talk through this so hopefully you can understand how I coded this.
The first var is a dropdown with 3 options.
The second is a dropdown with 2 options that don't affect the calculation.
The third is a user input that should work as long as the user inputs any number.
The fourth is a length inputed by a user. Should also work with any number.
The fifth is where I think something is getting messed up. Its a number as well but it has to be one of the numbers in the if/else table.

Personally I think I didn't code the if/else stuff correctly. Should the `var` element for `ohm` contain the if/else statement? Any help is greatly appreciated. I don't work in Javascript but my boss dumped this on me and said figure it out and this is where I ended up.

Thanks!

EDIT: HTML for those interested

```
  <body>
<h1>Voltage Drop Calculator Tool</h1> 
<form id=form1>
<div class="calculator-wrapper" id="voltageDropCalc" style="margin: 10px 0 20px 20px; padding: 15px;"><!-- BEGIN Calc wrapper --> 

<p>1. Initial Voltage</p>

<select name="voltDrop_volts" size="1" style="padding: 3px;"> <option>Choose...</option> <option value="12">12 Volt</option> <option value="24">24 Volt</option> </select>
<p>2. AC / DC</p>
<select class="sized" name="voltDrop_acdc" size="1" style="padding: 3px;"> <option selected="selected" value="dc">DC</option> <option value="ac">AC</option> </select>

<p class="field-label field-label-right">3. Current (Amps)</p>

<input align="bottom" class="sized" name="voltDrop_amps" size="15" style="padding: 3px;" type="text" />

<p class="field-label field-label-right">4. Cable Length (ft)</p>

<input align="bottom" class="sized" name="voltDrop_ft" size="15" style="padding: 3px;" type="text" />

<p class="field-label field-label-right">5. Cable Gauge (AWG)</p>
<input align="bottom" class="sized" name="voltDrop_awg" size="15" style="padding: 3px;" type="text" />

<p><a href="#" id="voltageDropSubmit" style="text-decoration: none;" onclick="printAnswer()"><button type="button">Calculate</button></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="clearBtn" href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><button type="button" onclick="formReset()">Cancel</button></a></p>
<div class="results-box">
<p id="theAnswer"style="margin: 10px 0;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</form>
<p>Note: Industry standard is a voltage drop of no greater than 10%.</p>


<div class="errorMsg"></div>
<!-- displays error messages to user -->
</div>
<!-- END Calc wrapper -->
</body>
```

Comment: what is `getElementsByName()`

Comment: without the complete context I don't think we can help

Comment: Well I thought it worked like getElementById. it was what my editor suggested and since the forms already were labeled with "names" instead of "id"s I ran with it.

Comment: Also, i do not see a declaration of "amp", but I do see "amps" declared.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be document.getElementsByName?

Comment: @user125697 in that case how will `awg` could have an int value

Comment: @Eric I changed the formula to "amps" and still no luck

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger such as Firebug?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I just opened it in firebug but I'm not sure what I'm looking at. It doesn't appear to find any errors though...but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things to correct here.

- First, you want to get the value of all your inputs inside the print answer function. Otherwise, your variables are initialized when the page is loaded, and the fields are not filled yet. move your code around like this

  ```
  function printAnswer()
  {
  var volts = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_volts")[0].value;
  var acdc = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_acdc")[0].value;
  var amps = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_amps")[0].value;
  var length = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_ft")[0].value);
  var awg = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_awg")[0].value;
  var ohm = 0;
  if (awg === 36) { ohm = 371.0; }
  else if (awg === 34) { ohm = 237.0; }
  else if (awg === 32) { ohm = 164.0; }
  else if (awg === 30) { ohm = 103.0; }
  else if (awg === 28) { ohm = 64.9; }
  else if (awg === 26) { ohm = 37.3; }
  else if (awg === 24) { ohm = 23.3; }
  else if (awg === 22) { ohm = 14.7; }
  else if (awg === 20) { ohm = 10.0; }
  else if (awg === 18) { ohm = 6.4; }
  else if (awg === 16) { ohm = 4.0; }
  else if (awg === 14) { ohm = 2.5; }
  else if (awg === 12) { ohm = 1.6; }
  else if (awg === 10) { ohm = 1.1; }
  else if (awg === 8) { ohm = .62; }
  else if (awg === 6) { ohm = .40; }
  else if (awg === 4) { ohm = .24; }
  else if (awg === 2) { ohm = .16; }
  else if (awg === 1) { ohm = .13; }
  else if (awg === '1/0') { ohm = .096; }
  else if (awg === '2/0') { ohm = .077; }
  else if (awg === '3/0') { ohm = .062; }
  else if (awg === '4/0') { ohm = .049; }
  else { msg = "Error"; }
  var vDrop = ((ohm * 2) * (length / 1000) * amps);
  var vFinal = (volts - vDrop);
  console.log(volts, acdc, amps, length, awg, ohm);
  document.getElementById("theAnswer").innerHTML = vFinal;
  }
  ```
- Also, keep in mind that what you get from a field is a string, so you might have to convert the values to numbers there, using parseInt() or parseFloat().

e.g: `var length = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_ft")[0].value);`

- Similarly, when you compare using ===, you want to compare objects of the same type. So if `awg` is a string, as you get it from th HTML, compare it to a string:

e.g: `if (awg === '6') { ... }`

- You can use `document.getElementsByName` or `document.getElementById` but bear in mind that the first returns a list, so you want to use [0], when the second one returns only one element. Also, for the second one to work, you will need you fields to have id set.
- Debug using the devtools and web console. Those are your best friends for this kind of debugging.

Comment: Thanks! After fudging around with it, I got it to work! I'll keep that in mind about the Name vs. Id. I have to make a few more of these calculators so I'm sure it will help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying it getElementsByName() should be document.getElementsByName() like this:

```
var volts = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_volts")[0].value;
var acdc = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_acdc")[0].value;
var amps = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_amps")[0].value;
var length = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_ft")[0].value;
var awg = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_awg")[0].value;
```

Tested:

```
<body>
<h1>Voltage Drop Calculator Tool</h1> 
<form id=form1>
<div class="calculator-wrapper" id="voltageDropCalc" style="margin: 10px 0 20px 20px; padding: 15px;"><!-- BEGIN Calc wrapper --> 

<p>1. Initial Voltage</p>

<select name="voltDrop_volts" size="1" style="padding: 3px;"> <option value="0">Choose...</option> <option value="12">12 Volt</option> <option value="24">24 Volt</option> </select>
<p>2. AC / DC</p>
<select class="sized" name="voltDrop_acdc" size="1" style="padding: 3px;"> <option selected="selected" value="dc">DC</option> <option value="ac">AC</option> </select>

<p class="field-label field-label-right">3. Current (Amps)</p>

<input align="bottom" class="sized" name="voltDrop_amps" size="15" style="padding: 3px;" type="text" />

<p class="field-label field-label-right">4. Cable Length (ft)</p>

<input align="bottom" class="sized" name="voltDrop_ft" size="15" style="padding: 3px;" type="text" />

<p class="field-label field-label-right">5. Cable Gauge (AWG)</p>
<input align="bottom" class="sized" name="voltDrop_awg" size="15" style="padding: 3px;" type="text" />

<p><a href="#" id="voltageDropSubmit" style="text-decoration: none;" onclick="printAnswer()"><button type="button">Calculate</button></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="clearBtn" href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><button type="button" onclick="formReset()">Cancel</button></a></p>
<div class="results-box">
<p id="theAnswer"style="margin: 10px 0;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</form>
<p>Note: Industry standard is a voltage drop of no greater than 10%.</p>


<div class="errorMsg"></div>
<!-- displays error messages to user -->
</div>
<!-- END Calc wrapper -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var volts = 0;
  var acdc = 0;
  var amps = 0;
  var length = 0;
  var awg = 0;
  var amp = 0;
 volts = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_volts")[0].value;
 acdc = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_acdc")[0].value;
 amps = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_amps")[0].value;
 length = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_ft")[0].value;
 awg = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_awg")[0].value;
var ohm = 0;

if (awg === 36) { ohm = 371.0; }
else if (awg === 34) { ohm = 237.0; }
else if (awg === 32) { ohm = 164.0; }
else if (awg === 30) { ohm = 103.0; }
else if (awg === 28) { ohm = 64.9; }
else if (awg === 26) { ohm = 37.3; }
else if (awg === 24) { ohm = 23.3; }
else if (awg === 22) { ohm = 14.7; }
else if (awg === 20) { ohm = 10.0; }
else if (awg === 18) { ohm = 6.4; }
else if (awg === 16) { ohm = 4.0; }
else if (awg === 14) { ohm = 2.5; }
else if (awg === 12) { ohm = 1.6; }
else if (awg === 10) { ohm = 1.1; }
else if (awg === 8) { ohm = .62; }
else if (awg === 6) { ohm = .40; }
else if (awg === 4) { ohm = .24; }
else if (awg === 2) { ohm = .16; }
else if (awg === 1) { ohm = .13; }
else if (awg === '1/0') { ohm = .096; }
else if (awg === '2/0') { ohm = .077; }
else if (awg === '3/0') { ohm = .062; }
else if (awg === '4/0') { ohm = .049; }
else { msg = "Error"; }

var vDrop = ((ohm * 2) * (length / 1000) * amp);
var vFinal = (volts - vDrop);

function formReset()
    {
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
    }
function printAnswer()
    {
        document.getElementById("theAnswer").innerHTML = vFinal;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Note that you're using "amp" when you are setting the value to the "amps"

Comment: in that case how will `awg` could have an int value

Comment: It is still returning an undefined error. I updated the post with the HTML

Comment: @DaronSpence I forgot add [0].value just edited. try again please.

Comment: @DaronSpence Note that you're using "amp" when you are setting the value to the "amps"

Comment: @kas3 thanks for doing all that. However, when I input anything into the fields, the answer displayed is 0. It's supposed to run the calculation with the user inputed data

Comment: I changed the formula to refelct "amps" instead of "amp"

Comment: @DaronSpence Huh, the problem is that your js logic should be executed after on click or submit form check this please: http://jsbin.com/umiret/1/edit

Comment: @kas3 I have no idea how to check that. Copy pasted the code for the submit and tweaked the names.

Comment: @DaronSpence it: http://jsbin.com/umiret/1/edit and remember that all your select options value should be a integer.

Comment: @kas3 So the output seems to be doing something now but the formula isn't being applied correctly.

Comment: @DaronSpence Well, check the fields values, that's all.

Comment: @kas3 I think I figured out whats wrong. Something in the formula is making the `var` "vDrop" equal to zero. Then when the next formula is ran, it takes the `var` "volts" and subtracts zero. Which is subsequently incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably want to use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByName`. To use `getElementById`, you must have the `id` attribute defined in your html.
2. You need to use the `value` property to get the value in the text box. For example:

   `var myValue = document.getElementById("myElement").value;`

Comment: edited the original post with updated JS and HTML. Still no luck